# Jupyter notebook's annoying grey text auto-show

Tags: jupyter-notebook, autocomplete, jupyter, annoy

After running a cell, that cell will show gray texts; if I click on the cell, they will disappear. Anyone ever encounter something like this before?
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21DCx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFHF8.png)

This is really annoying, If anyone know how to fix this, please help me.